# TYPO3: Using Page-Constants in HMENU / TMENU

Tags: menu, constants, typo3, typoscript

on a Page Template, I set a constant, such as

```
yl.page.backgroundColor = #ff0000
```

Now, is there a way to access the BackgroundColor-Value of a menu item, that is rendered by TMENU? I was thinking somewhat like this:

```
lib.mainNavigation.1.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li style="background-color: {$record.yl.page.backgroundColor}">|</li>
```

Using only {$yl.page.backgroundColor} will - of course - render the color set on the current page, not the one I set on the respective menu item...

The getText reference unfortunately does not even contain the Word "Constant".

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are trying to do, but that's not the way TypoScript works. Indeed the data from the current page is used when {$yl.page.backgroundColor}.

To achieve what you are trying to you will need to come up with a little dirt. I would suggest you store your background color in one of the unused fields of the pages (for example subtitle if you don't use this). Otherwise you can of course also add a field to the page table and use that instead.

Next step is to load your background color (set in my case in the field "subtitle") into your wrap with something like the following.

```
lib.mainNavigation.1.NO.wrapItemAndSub.dataWrap = <li style="background-color: {field:subtitle}">|</li>
```

Comment: That is indeed possible, I had tried a similar way (by defining my custom field in the TCA). But I am switching to constants because of its native inheritance behaviour. I would like to have the background color inherited... And I don't really want to have both the field and a constant redundantly...

Comment: The only way you can do that with constants is if you create a separate PHP script which renders the entire template of the specified  page.

If you would like to use a slide ability, then there is something like that inside TypoScript. You will need to use a database field though.

data = levelfield:-1,subtitle,slide